# AngularJS Eclipse plugin Install button missing

Tags: eclipse, angularjs

I am trying to install AngularJS plugin from Eclipse marketplace in Eclipse Kepler but the install button is not present. (I searched for Angular in Eclipse marketplace)

Could someone pls. help in this regards. I tried google search but nothing of help.

All I found was that I need to have nodejs plugin pre-installed in Eclipse which I did but that also didn't help.

Comment: Please retry it, I have updated AngularJS Eclipse marketplace to add the well features ids. Now you should have the Install button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this URL to your Eclipse Installation to reach the plugin:

```
http://oss.opensagres.fr/angularjs-eclipse/0.3.0/
```